# Write FTP errors/debug result to a database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the FTP class in Codeigniter to send some files via FTP.

The FTP script is run using a cron job and is automated.

I've set the config debug setting to true, but the trouble is the user won't see it since the script is run automatically by the server.

Any ideas on how to write FTP debug errors to a database? Or return the result of the transfer (success/fail)? I'd like to be able to show the user what the errors are if the file fails to transfer. I can't seem to find any info on it and there's nothing in the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could send stdout from cron to a script that sends the output as a POST var to another controller/function to insert into db

```
#cron
0 0 0 0 0 php /myscript/ftp 2>&1 | curlSend.sh


#curlSend.sh
#!/bin/bash
myvar=`cat /dev/stdin`
curl -d"test=$myvar" http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/ftp/log


ftp/log

function log(){
   $entry = $_POST['test'];//insert into db
```